# ¿Cómo puedo evitar la ejecución directa de comandos de WSL desde la consola de Windows?

Tags: cmd, wsl

Tengo instalada una distribución Ubuntu como wsl2 en Windows 10. Desde la consola de Windows (cmd) puedo ejecutar comandos de Ubuntu, anteponiendo `wsl`. Por ejemplo:

```
wsl cat file_1.txt
```

El problema es que sin anteponer `wsl`, los comandos de Linux se ejecutan igual, y esto es lo que querría evitar ya que se presta a confusión. ¿Existe alguna manera de prevenir esto?

Para aclarar mi pregunta, lo que quiero conseguir es que los comandos de Linux solo se ejecuten si antepongo `wsl`. Es decir, que esta instrucción no se ejecutaría (daría error):

```
cat file_1.txt
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que está ejecutando el comando en wsl? Pon `where cat` para ver qué es lo que estás ejecutando realmente.

Comment: Efectivamente, no era la wsl sino la distribución de Git for Windows, que incluye estas herramientas. Eliminando el directorio de la Path se resuelve el problema. Gracias!

Comment: La respuesta deberia ir en el campo respuesta... no editando la pregunta.. si no, no se entiende...

Comment: Repasa la ayuda de SOes si tienes dudas sobre cómo publicar tu propia solución a la pregunta.

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Siguiendo la sugerencia de [Mateo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/169744/mateo), he usado `where cat` para chequear si realmente se estaba ejecutando desde la wsl, y resulta que no era la wsl sino la distribución de Git for Windows, que incluye estas herramientas. Eliminando el directorio `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` de la PATH se resuelve el problema.